# How to customize appearance of "TODO" in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am using Intellij IDEA 15.03 on a Mac. One of the first things I do after installing Intellij on a new machine is customize the appearance of the code. This question, in particular, is about the customization of the TODO defaults.

In **Editor > Color & Fonts > General**, I have the following setting:

[image: todo default]

This definition, along with some other customizations, is saved under a separate Scheme, say `S`.

Additionally, under **Editor > Inspections**, the settings are as shown below:

[image]

In my code, however, the white-on-red look that I set up is not showing up, and every TODO comment is simply shown as a  warning with the standard yellowed background. The severity setting seems to be overwriting my scheme setting. How do I get the setting shown in the first picture here?

Here is a sample from my code, as is being currently displayed by Intellij IDEA:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the highlighting you want by disabling the "TODO Comment" inspection. The inspection is disabled by default, so you must have enabled it yourself.

As the description shown on your screenshot says, the inspection is intended to be used in batch mode (when you run Analyze | Inspect Code manually), and not for on-the-fly editor highlighting.